# Retracing steps after composer update introduced log error

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm working on my first laravel project, using laravel 5.1.28, homestead, and postgres.

Recently I updated composer.json for the first time in a while (and did composer update for the first time in a while), and now everything looks good in my sandbox, but my builds fail in heroku with the following error:

Generating optimized autoload files

> php artisan clear-compiled
>      PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /tmp/build_4b890192877bdbf1f605fbefdc7b2f34/dianekaplan-Family-laravel-e49374e/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:741

I've read through about 5 threads for this error and tried the various fixes that resolved the different issues others had to lead to this error, but none of them seem to be mine.

So a different question: how do I go back in time from the perspective of composer?  Does the composer.lock ride along with git so I could theoretically go back to that point, be able to have successful builds again, and then do a composer update again one day when I have a buddy and time to work through the fallout?  (I'm a newbie, so an issue like this is crippling)

What approach can get me back to where I was for the time being?

Based on feedback in the comments I tried: 
 - replacing my composer.lock with a version that was in place back when builds were still succeeding (thank you, git!), then doing composer install (rather than update, so it would honor those old version numbers)- but afterward the build still failed with that same error above
 -  composer dump, composer update --no-scripts, and composer update (in that order), but afterward the build still failed with that same error above

:(:(:(

Here's what's in my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",

        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0",
        "laracasts/flash": "^1.3",
        "cloudinary/cloudinary_php": "dev-master",
        "jrm2k6/cloudder": "0.2.*",
        "Illuminate/Support": "^5.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "laracasts/generators": "^1.1"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/mailers"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you use git or some other version control?

Comment: try: composer dump, composer update --no-scripts, and composer update in that order.

Comment: Thank you so much for your ideas- I'm flying blind so I really appreciate the help.  Ayo Akinyemi, I did that but my subsequent build still fails with the same error.  @user3158900: yes I use git- can it help me here?  I manually replaced my composer.lock, and did composer install, and the error still happened.  Is there a better way to go?

Comment: Could you add your composer.json contents to the question? It's likely this is caused by an old dependency that should be removed.

Comment: Sure!  Added now above- thanks @tjbp

Comment: It may be `illuminate/html` which is the problem as it's been abandoned.  Try changing it to `laravelcollective/html`.  It should be a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried `composer update` on a 5.1 app using your composer.json, and didn't run into any issues - so the error likely comes from code somewhere in your app - it looks likely that you're using the `Log` facade to log something, eg. `Log::error('message')`, but you've written it as `log::error('message')`. After finding that, you may still have the same error when updating, in which case temporarily remove the following from composer.json before running `composer update`:

```
"pre-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled"
],
```

On a side note there are a couple of other issues in your dependencies:

- `illuminate/html` is deprecated/abandoned, replace it with `laravelcollective/html` instead.
- `illuminate/support` is a part of `laravel/framework`, so is unnecessary and can be removed.